# Seg fault while assigning memory to pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault

I get seg fault when I try to assign memory to a object pointer (trying to dynamically create a 1D array). What am I doing wrong? I first I though it must be due to the kind of type T being used, but this happens even for native data types such as int. I come from a C background (new to C++), where I would have done memory allocation using malloc/calloc.

e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
struct test {
   T *element;
}

class Foo {

    Foo() {
    //empty
    }
    // as an example using T to be int
    test<int> *t;

    template <typename T>
    void setup(int n) {
      t->element = new T[n];
    }

    void run() {
      setup(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: dynamically allocating an array with new is the least recommendet approach to do so. have a look at containers and smartpointers.

Comment: `error: invalid use of template-name ‘test’ without an argument list`

Comment: You're missing a `;` after all your classes.

Comment: How come everyone assumes manual allocation is wrong? Most of the time I need low level memory management it's because I'm writing my own container. Or high-performance database. Or whatever. Do we have to assume the worst?

Comment: @Cameron "Most of the time I need low level memory management it's because I'm writing my own container." why are you writing your own container? And why do you assume newbies should be doing this?

Comment: @Neil: Usually for performance, but sometimes for convenience too. There's no packed nibble vector in `std`, for example. At one point I needed a faster hash container (with less strict iterator guarantees). Need a special tree? Not in `std`. Etc. I get your point about newbies, I just wish the default view was optimistic instead of pessimistic.

Comment: @Cameron I've seen so many instances of hand-crafted hash tables that were a disaster. Yes, they were (sometimes) a little bit faster than those in the Standard Library, but they were a  bug-ridden, maintenance nightmare. They should definitely be a last resort.

Comment: @Cameron [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: `setup` is a template function, so you have to call it as `setup<int>(10)`

Comment: You should probably make `Foo` a templated class, rather than templating specific functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, `t` is never initialized, so dereferencing it in `setup` causes a segfault.

Comment: I fixed it. I can't post the actually code I am using, so I quickly created something similar to be posted here. I should have compiled and tested the sample code too. My bad, will do it next time.

Comment: >>Simple, t is never initialized, so dereferencing it in setup causes a segfault.

Oh, I can't believe I missed something this trivial! :(
Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in `t->element = new T[n]`, you access member `element` on a (probably) non initialised data member `t`.

Comment: This is wrong. `t` is `test<int>*`, not `T*`. It should be `t = new test<int>;`